# Searching for VoltDB ODBC Driver

Tags: voltdb

can someone tell me if there is a VoltDB ODBC Driver and where I can find it? I were not able to find one.

I need ODBC Driver for a benchmarking tool. The tool should compare different NewSQL Databases.

Kind regards Sedros

Answer (score 2):

The ODBC driver for VoltDB is no longer available. I work at VoltDB.